# Is it necessary to declare prototypes of functions?

Tags: c++

Compare

```
int foo (int n) {
 return n;
}
```

vs

```
int foo(int);

int foo (int n) {
 return n;
}
```

Is there any reason to declare function prototypes in C++ beforehand? I come from a JAVA background, so I have never ever declared function prototypes, and this is somewhat new to me.

Comment: The definition also serves as a declaration. One or the other needs to happen before the function is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any name shall be declared before its using. So if you use a function name it shall be declared. A definition of a function is at the same time its declaration. So there is no need to write

```
int foo(int);

int foo (int n) {
 return n;
}
```

It is enough simply to define the function

```
int foo (int n) {
 return n;
}
```

Take into account that a compilation unit may contain several declarations of the same function that are not its definition..

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not required to write prototypes if the called function is written *before* the calling function. Prototypes are written so that the compiler can understand that the declared function is defined later. So in that case, even if the called function is written *after* than calling function, it won't raise any error.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to declare the function before definition if you want to use it.

for ex

```
int foo ();

int main(...)
{
  //I can use foo now 
  int x = foo(): 

}
```

Now while this seams like a small win it makes a much bigger difference once you want a function shared across multiple cpp files which you will eventually need because no one can manage a 1 million line source code file.

So now I have

foo.h

```
int Foo();
```

I can now use Foo() in any source by including the header

main.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"
int main(..)
{
   //I can use it here 
   Foo(); 
}
```

bob.cpp

```
#inlcude "foo.h"
int doSomething()
{
    // and here 
    Foo();
}
```

And I only define it in foo.cpp;

First this is required.  If you put the definition in the header your would fall afoul of the [one definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule). The other big advantage is it makes your compile times much faster as you could see if you changed this function to a template function which would allow you to bypass the odr.